# Is it possible to have the maven timestamp twice in two different formats?

Tags: java, maven, date, datetime

I currently have

```
<properties>
  <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
</properties>
```

but I need a date time (like above) and just a date.

It it possible to parse configure maven.build.timestamp.format twice in maven?

I have tried

```
 <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
 <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
 <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
 <date>${maven.build.timestamp}</date>
```

but I only get the yyyy-MM-dd format in both.